# Vectors and polyhedra: a surprising fact

Tags: geometry, education, vector-analysis, vectors

Given a $n$-faced polyhedron, associate to each face an outward-pointing normal vector with length equal to the area of that face. Show that the sum of these $n$ vectors is zero.

I've already proved the cases $n=4, n=6$, that is when the polyhedron is respectively a tetrahedron and a six-faced polyhedron (the last one is a combination of two tetrahedra with two congruent faces). Is there a way to show this using combinations of tetrahedra?

Comment: You can decompose a polyhedron into the union of tetrahedra whose interiors are disjoint and which meet in full faces, like you did for $n=6$. (This is the three-dimensional analogue of a triangulation of a polygon.) That's probably what you're looking for. By the way, don't forget $n=5$!

Comment: @GregMartin the 120-gon is known to be troublesome.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a bit buzzed after an evening of jazz, so I swat this with a cannonball.

This follows from [the divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#Divergence_theorem). Let $\vec{u}$ be any constant vector. Let
$V$ be that polyhedron, $\partial V$ its boundary, and $\vec{S}_i, i=1,\ldots, N,$ the vectors that you listed.

By the divergence theorem the sum
$$
\vec{u}\cdot\sum_i\vec{S}_i=\oint_{\partial V}\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{S}=\int_V\nabla\cdot\vec{u}\,dV.
$$
But because $\vec{u}$ is constant its divergence vanishes. Therefore so does this integral. Consequently
$$
\vec{u}\cdot\sum_i\vec{S}_i=0.
$$
But here $\vec{u}$  was arbitrary, so this can happen only if 
$$\sum_i\vec{S}_i=\vec{0}.$$

Comment: The method outlined by Greg Martin in a comment above is surely the way to go. Just riffing.

Comment: The OP did ask whether it was possible to use a "combination of tetrahedra", so the tetrahedral decomposition is precisely the answer to the question.  But for proving the fact about the vectors, I like your way.

Comment: Isn't this significant enough to have some name attached to it? What about some corollaries ? For example if A(a,0,0), B(0,b,0) and C(0,0,c)  then the area of ABC is $$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}$$.

Comment: @EugenIonascu - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem